# Very slow query when combining order by id desc and not exists

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `id` != 1
    AND `users`.`activated` = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `blockings`
        WHERE (blockings.user_id = users.id
            AND blockings.blocked_id = 1)
        OR(blockings.blocked_id = users.id
            AND blockings.user_id = 1))
ORDER BY
    users.id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It takes 5 seconds to complete this query on a 30k rows table

It takes a moment to complete when I remove NOT EXISTS part

There is Index on users.id and blockings.user_id and blockings.blocked_id

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: Do you need EVERYTHING in the row?  Maybe you can limit the * of the select down to JUST the columns you need?

Comment: @easleyfixed doesn't change anything. still takes 4.5 seconds

Comment: Hmm ok, so the search its self versus the pull is the delay ..just making sure.  Well, I was going to suggest indexing, but you already have that.  What version of MySQL are you running and is the data on SSD drives perhaps?

Comment: mysql 8.0.28 aws rds

Comment: When asking query-optimization questions on Stack Overflow, please include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for each table in your query, so we don't have to guess at columns, data types, or indexes. Also please include the EXPLAIN for the current query and tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a *"stab in the dark"* as you have not included your table definitions or EXPLAIN output for your current query in your question.

With single column indices on `blockings.user_id` and `blockings.blocked_id` you *should* be seeing an index_merge for `blockings` in the EXPLAIN output for your current query.

With PK `(user_id, blocked_id)` and an index on `(blocked_id, user_id)` using a UNION in your NOT EXISTS is likely to be much faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.id != 1
  AND u.activated = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM blockings b
        WHERE b.user_id = u.id AND b.blocked_id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        FROM blockings b
        WHERE b.blocked_id = u.id AND b.user_id = 1
    )
ORDER BY u.id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

As suggested by MatBailie, it is worth trying with the UNION ALL split into two separate NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.id != 1
AND u.activated = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM blockings b
    WHERE b.user_id = u.id AND b.blocked_id = 1
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM blockings b
    WHERE b.blocked_id = u.id AND b.user_id = 1
)
ORDER BY u.id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: I would use two NOT EXISTS statements (combined with AND) rather than UNION ALL

Comment: I tried both and got slightly better performance (negligible) from the UNION ALL but I guess it will depend on the distribution of OP's data. Definitely worth OP trying both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible alternative query and you may need to add index on the columns used in the where clause.

```
SELECT
    users.id,  /* all the necessary columns goes here */
    users.name,
    users. Email
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN blockings ON (
        (blockings.user_id = users.id AND blockings.blocked_id = 1)
        OR (blockings.blocked_id = users.id AND blockings.user_id = 1)
    )
WHERE
    users.id != 1
    AND users.activated = 1
    AND blockings.id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    users.id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: The OR is still going to be a problem.